# Solver options ignored?

Tags: drake

```
solver = SnoptSolver()
options = SolverOptions()
options.SetOption(solver.id(), "Time limit", 2)
options.SetOption(solver.id(), "Major iterations limit", 200)
options.SetOption(solver.id(), "Minor iterations limit", 100)

result = solver.Solve(prog, None, options)
```

I've been using the above code to try to limit the Snopt iterations, but it is having no noticeable effect on the runtime. It still takes up to 25 seconds. Am I setting the limit correctly?

Comment: Don't know Drake, but I usually inspect the SNOPT log file to see why it stopped.

Comment: Could you add the print file with
options.SetOption(solver.id(), "Print file", "my_print.out")? Then you can check the print file `my_print.out` and see what happens.